# Prove that if $C \in \overrightarrow{AB}$ and $C \neq A$, then $\overrightarrow{AB} = \overrightarrow{AC}$

Tags: geometry

Prove that if $C \in \overrightarrow{AB}$ and $C \neq A$, then $\overrightarrow{AB} = \overrightarrow{AC}$.

I am a little confused on how to go about this. In particular, what axioms to apply because I do not know if I am allowed to apply the "Incidence Axioms" to this exercise.

I believe two rays are said to be equal if they share a common point which is not the apex, but then I am not sure what is supposed to be said because I feel tht solves the problem.

I know $C$ lies in the ray $AB$. I know $C \neq A$. Then $AC = AB$ because $C \in AB$.

But do I have to invoke any specific axioms? I feel it is too simple.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a definition of $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and the axioms you are supposed to prove the statement from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\textbf{Definition (Ray)}$. Given two distinct points $A$, $B$, the ray $\vec{AB}$ is the set consisting of $A$, plus all points on the line $AB$ that are on the same side of $A$ as $B$.

If $C\in\vec{AB}$, by the axiom (B$3$), it happens that $A\star C \star B$ or $A\star B\star C$, where $\star$ denotes the relation of betweenness. In both cases, $A$ is not in the segment $\overline{BC}$, so $B$ is on the same side of $A$ as $C$ (so $B\in\vec{AC}$) and $C$ is on the same side of $A$ as $B$ (so $C\in\vec{AB}$)

Let $D\in \vec{AB}$ be a point distinct of $A$ and $C$.

$(1)$ If $A\star D\star C$, $A$ is not in the segment $\overline{DC}$, so $D$ is on the same side of $A$ as $C$ (so $D\in\vec{AC}$).

$(2)$ If $A\star C\star D$, $A$ is not in the segment $\overline{DC}$, so $D$ is on the same side of $A$ as $C$ (so $D\in\vec{AC}$).

Hence, $\vec{AB}\subset \vec{AC}$. Doing the same thing but reversal, we get  $\vec{AC}\subset \vec{AB}$, so the equality holds.